# Node/Express IIS Reverse Proxy Slow Performance

Tags: node.js, express, iis

I'm hosting a Node/Express application on Windows Server through IIS. I've created a reverse proxy to redirect to localhost:3000 which is where my Node app is running.

The node app can be accessed by another computer on the network by navigating to `node-app/`. All endpoints can be accessed and everything seems to work fine.

However when making database changes i.e: updating/inserting records the changes are processed by the database instantly, but the site doesn't reflect the changes until **multiple minutes** after the change is made.

The latency however **completely disappears** if providing the port to the URL i.e: `node-app:3000/`. This had led me to the conclusion that the issue must be in the url rewriting/reverse proxy processes? My web.config is as follows:

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:3000/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This is a bit foreign territory for me, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi there! This might be related to caching, but I cannot say for sure. Do you see any kind of cache headers when inspecting your requests in e.g. chrome dev tools?

Comment: Thank you for steering me in the right direction! Led me to the solution below..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to user `abondoa` for mentioning caching! There is a setting in IIS called `Output caching`.

Disabling this setting allowed the changes to reflect instantly as they should!

Comment: But this is completely the wrong approach if you read that comment. For dynamic pages, you should tune their cache headers to prevent them from being cached. Turning off IIS Output Caching, however, stops server side caching for all kinds of contents (even the things that should be cached there).

Comment: Many people use Mozilla's doc site, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control but a search engine can give you more materials.